# NullReferenceException when trying to call a function from another script in unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

The script that I'm trying to run the function from looks like this:

```
public class switchAnimation : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Character;
    private Animator myController;

    void Awake()
    {
        myController = Character.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void playPositive_large()
    {
        myController.SetTrigger("P_l");
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to run it from another script:

```
68: switchAnimation SA = GetComponent<switchAnimation>();
69: SA.playPositive_large();
```

But it gives me the following error:

> "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Buttons.myAnims (UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData baseEvent) (at Assets/Main_A1/Buttons.cs:69)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall`1[UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData].Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:189)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:637)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:773)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1[T0].Invoke (.T0 arg0) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_1.cs:53)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger.Execute (EventTriggerType id, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/EventTrigger.cs:67)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger.OnPointerEnter (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/EventTrigger.cs:73)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerEnterHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:22)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerEnterHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
>   "

I tried different ways of calling the function but more or less I get the same error!

Comment: Is your both script in the same gameObject? if it's not, then you have to get reference to your other gameObject, then call otherGameObject.GetComponent<switchAnimation>();

Comment: No They're not. How can I get reference to the other gameObject?I tried using a gameObject but it also didn't work.

Comment: that's why you get NullReference, take a look at the duplicate question to find what is a NullReference. you will have to get reference to gameObject which has AnotherScript, and you doing it by creating a public variable like, `public GameObject otherGameObject;` and don't forget to attach your otherGameObject in the inspector, then you can call `otherGameObject.GetComponent<switchAnimation>();`

Comment: See the updated duplicate link. It shows how to fix this now.